# Hash shows as populated in console, but size is 0

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Would anyone be able to explain why I can't correctly determine the size of a prototype hash.

The following prints out `klass {_object: Object, test: "foo", each: function, eachSlice: function, all: function…}` proving that the "test" pair is definitely getting added. But the size prints as 0.

```
this.state = new Hash();

this.state["test"] = "foo";

console.log(this.state.size());
console.log(this.state);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're just adding a normal property to the `Hash` instance. You need to actually add an element to the hash, with the [`.set()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Hash/prototype/set/) method:

```
this.state.set("test", "foo");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Rmty9/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize the hash with data in it like so.

```
var state = $H({'test':'foo','moretest':'bar'});

console.log(state.size()); // returns 2
console.log(state.get('moretest')); returns bar
```